# Plotting Smoother Multiple Lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset which contains three variables, species, CO2 and stomatal density. I'm looking to create a plot which has a line for each species to show how stomatal density changes over C02 for each species. I have used the following code.

```r
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
    
# Separate into Species
don <- mydata %>% 
      filter(Species %in% c("Alnus glutinosa", "Betula pendula", "Betula pubescens", "Corylus avellana", "Quercus petrea", "Sorbus aucuparia"))
      
    # Plot
    don %>%
      ggplot( aes(x=CO2, y=Stomatal_Density, group=Species, color=Species))  +
      geom_line()
```

The code works, however, the lines for each plot don't look great as can be seen.

[image: graph with jagged lines]

I tried replacing `geom_line()` with `geom_smooth()` however no lines appear on the graph. Is there a way that I could make these lines look better?

Update: Here's my data

```
    dput(mydata)
structure(list(Species = c("Alnus glutinosa", "Alnus glutinosa", 
"Alnus glutinosa", "Alnus glutinosa", "Alnus glutinosa", "Alnus glutinosa", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", 
"Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pendula", "Betula pubescens", 
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", 
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", 
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", 
"Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", 
"Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", 
"Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", 
"Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", 
"Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana", "Corylus avellana","Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", 
"Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", 
"Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", 
"Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", "Quercus petrea", "Sorbus aucuparia", 
"Sorbus aucuparia", "Sorbus aucuparia", "Sorbus aucuparia", "Sorbus aucuparia", 
"Sorbus aucuparia", "Sorbus aucuparia", "Sorbus aucuparia"), 
    CO2 = c(356.45, 371.14, 371.14, 371.14, 375.8, 391.65, 358.87, 
    358.87, 358.87, 358.87, 358.87, 358.87, 358.87, 358.87, 358.87, 
    361.2, 361.2, 361.2, 361.2, 361.2, 363.55, 363.55, 363.55, 
    363.55, 337.86, 373.47, 373.47, 373.47, 373.47, 387.63, 389.63, 
    392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 
    392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 
    392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 393.83, NA, NA, 354.39, 356.46, 356.46, 
    358.87, 361.2, 353.83, 387.63, 389.63, 393.83, 409.39, 411.18, 
    356, 371.14, 371.14, 371.14, 375.8, 389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 
    389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 
    389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 389.63, 291, 300.6, 
    300.6, 356.46, 356.46, 356.46, 363.55, 363.55, 366.75, 370.19, 
    370.19, 406.62, 409.39, 409.39, 409.39, 305, 356, 356, 362.61, 
    371.14, 371.14, 371.14, 377.52), SD = c(108, 218.75, 218.75, 
    92.01388889, 107.85, NA, 60, 108.1, 135.6, 128.4, 115.1, 
    202.6, 102.4, 65.9, 39.3, 45, 79.5, 105.2, 93.9, 75.3, 79.3, 
    62, 93.9, 81.4, 101, 66.8, 132.81, 132.81, 92.45, 174.6, 
    160, 243.68, 187.98, 229.76, 222.76, 208.87, 160.13, 194.95, 
    215.83, 222.79, 201.91, 208.87, 187.98, 250.64, 181.02, 292.42, 
    264.57, 257.61, 264.57, 243.68, 14, 127, 143, NA, 147, 61, 
    87.8, 65, 124.5, 111.1, 107, 12.6, 2.99, 2.99, 225, 164.9305556, 
    164.9305556, 101.5625, 84, 113.64, 95.25, 98.32, 94.38, 107.34, 83.08, 96.45, 91.48, 92.11, 90.8, 99.6, 91.45, 117.73, 83.33, 
    96.28, 88.26, 110.58, 698, 810, 468, 510, 370, 405, 47.5, 
    19.6, 4.6, 394.3, 355.1, 333, 215.14, 168.06, 175.33, 118, 
    224, 132, 132, 157.1180556, 157.1180556, 99.39236111, 73.9
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -109L))
```

Comment: What is alls here? can you post `dput(alls)` here. So that you get better help from community

Comment: Try saving the picture with `ggsave`. I suspect that the output you provided a _screenshot_ of is of much more poor quality than what a saved file will be.

Comment: Sorry I had my data set saved as alls, I've changed it now to mydata so that it's easier to understand. Thank you for your helpful comment.

Comment: Sorry, I added a saved image of my plot, hopefully, this will be of better quality. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: If you run the output of `dput(mydata)` like @PKumar mentioned that would be helpful so we can grab your data and play around with it. I'm still not sure what to do about the lines though - that is the standard output.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't understood the comment properly, thank you for your help. Hopefully, I displayed the data correctly. Thank you so much everyone for your help, I greatly appreciate your time and expertise.

Comment: @Carey Caginalp I was hoping to find a way to make a trend line that shows the overall direction of each species and doesn't simply go from one data point to the next, for example in a similar graph that I made with a different data set that only contained a single species, I used geom_smooth() to produce a trend line which suited the data well and showed the overall trend. However, this didn't work when I tried it in the above issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I think of is to put a line through the points, and maybe change the individual points to scatter instead. The line doesn't appear to be a fantastic approximation for all of the groups, but perhaps it's a start.

```
don %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=CO2, y=SD, group=Species, color=Species))  +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y ~ a * x + b, se = F,
              method.args = list(start = list(a = 0.1, b = 0.1)))
```

[image: Output]

Comment: why are you using `nls` for a linear fit?  That's crazy overkill ... `geom_smooth(method="lm")` will get you the same results more efficiently ...

Comment: Thank you very much @Carey Caginalp, that graph is definitely much better than the one I could make. The explanation as well was also very helpful. Thank you so much, I spent a long time struggling with this graph and your help, time and expertise are very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard for R to make very smooth lines since some of your groups have very few unique points:

```r
don %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(n=length(unique(CO2)))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Species              n
  <chr>            <int>
1 Alnus glutinosa      4
2 Betula pendula      10
3 Betula pubescens    10
4 Corylus avellana     4
5 Quercus petrea       8
6 Sorbus aucuparia     5
```

Unfortunately I don't know of a super-easy way to create different kinds of *flexible* smooths (i.e. lines that are smooth but not necessarily as simple as straight lines) for groups with different numbers of points (some large enough for `geom_smooth`, some not), or to make `geom_smooth()` robust so that it skips groups where smoothing fails (rather than just failing).  You could add linear regression lines, which will work as long as there are at least two x-values per group:

```r
ggplot(don, aes(x=CO2, y=SD, group=Species, color=Species))  + 
   geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

You can make things a *little* bit better by drawing a line through the mean values for each unique CO2 level:

```r
ggplot(don, aes(x=CO2, y=SD, group=Species, color=Species))  + 
     geom_point() + stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="line")
```

but there is still a big dip for *Quercus petrea* (what's going on with those data anyway?)

(You could use `geom_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~poly(x,2))`, which would give you quadratic fits ... this would be a little more flexible than assuming a straight line ...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Ben Bolker, I greatly appreciate it. Your explanation was extremely helpful. I will try what you suggested now. Yes I agree, the data is not great, it's from a systematic review I conducted due to the reduced ability to collect my own data due to the pandemic. It is an area that is very understudied and that is the reason for the lack of data points. The data, if anything, highlights the need for more study in this area. I greatly appreciate all of your help, time and expertise, thank you.